# Does PhpStorm run its own Docker containers in the background?

Tags: docker, intellij-idea, containers, phpstorm, jetbrains-ide

I want to grasp better what's going on behind the scenes when developing with Docker in JetBrains' IDEs, in this case PhpStorm.

I see that my project root directory is mapped to `/opt/project` but when I `docker-compose up` and look inside the PHP container `/opt/project` doesn't exist. So I'm guessing that PhpStorm manages it's own Docker environment where it deploys my containers.

Is it true that there are actually 3 domains to consider?

1. The code on the local machine
2. The Docker containers ran by PhpStorm -> I can run tests via PhpStorm
3. The Docker containers ran by `docker-compose up` -> I can see the website

Can somebody verify that what I stated is correct and provide more context? And if what I stated is correct, it poses another question like why I don't have port conflicts between the PhpStorm Docker containers and my own ran by `docker-compose up`.

These questions started popping up while configuring the tests (PHPUnit), dependency management (composer, autoload, composer dump-autoload) in PhpStorm.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the insides of IDE's Docker integration aren't documented.

> I see that my project root directory is mapped to /opt/project but when I docker-compose up and look inside the PHP container /opt/project doesn't exist.

Where do you see it? How do you look inside exactly?

> Is it true that there are actually 3 domains to consider?
>
> 1. The code on the local machine

I'm unfortunately not sure what do you mean here exactly. Volume mappings?

> 2. The Docker containers ran by PhpStorm -> I can run tests via PhpStorm

PhpStorm is indeed using "helper" containers to run tests.

> 3. The Docker containers ran by docker-compose up -> I can see the website

Yes?..

> why I don't have port conflicts between the PhpStorm Docker containers and my own ran by docker-compose up

Could you please be more specific? How did you set up ports? What ports should be conflicting? How did you test that there are no conflicts?

> These questions started popping up while configuring the tests

Are you facing some specific issue?

Comment: I had a similar problem and it was related to python-plugin in IntelliJ. Seemingly IntelliJ and the derived products use this kind of special shadow-mapping to /opt/project. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/60337001/834309 for the full question with config-details.