# Running PHPUnit in Intellij with docker remote interpreter from docker-compose expects project in "/opt/project"

Tags: php, docker, intellij-idea, docker-compose, phpunit

I have a PHP symfony project loaded in IntelliJ (2019.3.2, Build #IU-193.6015.39) with the following structure (left out irrelevant files like README, etc):

```
<project_root>
+- src/
+- tests/
+- vendor/
|  +- autoload.php    
+- .env
+- composer.json
+- composer.lock
+- docker-compose.yml
+- Dockerfile
+- phpunit.xml
+- phpunit-custom.xml
```

The project interpreter is set to use remote docker (Docker for Mac) by docker-compose and IntelliJ detects the interpreter and debugger correctly:
[image]

docker-compose.yml has the following structure:

```
version: "2"

services:
    app:
        build: .
        env_file:
            - ./.env
        ports:
            - 8888:80
        volumes:
            - ./:/var/www/
            - .docker/app-dev/nginx/fastcgi-timeouts.conf:/etc/nginx/fastcgi-timeouts.conf
            - .docker/app-dev/php/conf.d/00_opcache.ini:/etc/php/conf.d/00_opcache.ini
            - .docker/app-dev/php/conf.d/30_xdebug.ini:/etc/php/conf.d/30_xdebug.ini
            - .docker/app-dev/php/php-fpm-settings.conf:/etc/php/php-fpm-settings.conf

    db:
        image: mysql:5.6
        environment:
            MYSQL_DATABASE: project_database
            MYSQL_USER: user
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: password
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: master_password
        ports:
            - 3306:3306
        volumes:
            - mysql-data:/var/lib/mysql:delegated
            - .docker/db/mysqld.cnf:/etc/mysql/conf.d/mysqld.cnf
            - .docker/db/000-structure.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/000-structure.sql
            - .docker/db/001-data.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/001-data.sql
            - .docker/db/002-test-data.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/002-test-data.sql

volumes:
    mysql-data:
```

So the project is mounted into the container's `/var/www`. After spinning up the project with `docker-compose up -d` it is accessible on `http://localhost:8888` as expected. But running the unit-tests through IntelliJ does not work as the resulting command expects the configuration in `/opt/project` folder of the container:

```sh
[docker-compose://[/Users/me/projects/symfony_with_db/docker-compose.yml]:app/]:php /opt/.phpstorm_helpers/phpunit.php --configuration /opt/project/phpunit-custom.xml
Could not read "/opt/project/phpunit-custom.xml".

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Whereas the path to the configuration-file has to be provided as an absolute path in the UI.
[image]

Entering the project-relative path does not work.
[image]
So there seems to be no way to tell IntelliJ to look into the path, where the project is actually mounted.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have a similar issue and I could't find any option in Intellij settings, so I need to manually change paths in `.idea` directory. Try search for `/opt/project` inside `.idea` directory and replace it with `/var/www`.

In my case, this issue was caused by the Python plugin in my Intellij Ultimate 2019.3

Comment: Indeed just disabling the python plugin solved the issue. Interestingly all the PHP-related `.xml` files inside `.idea` folder still reference `/opt/project` but seem to get overridden by project's path-mappings (`{PROJECT-ROOT} -> /var/www`).

Comment: This used to work in my setup, then it didn't now I know why :) Is there a bug report I can +1 ?

Comment: I am not aware of any related bug-report.

Answer (score 0):

The field you are looking for is in Settings > Test Frameworks > [Interpreter] > Test Runner > Default configuration file.
I use absolute path in container to phpunit.xml and works fine.

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/php-test-frameworks.html#phpunit-test-runner

Comment: Thank you for the answer. As pointed out in https://stackoverflow.com/a/60343667/834309 the reason was another plugin somehow overriding the configured (absolute) path.